My Cookie is 1 browser refresh late from RootLayout compare to middleware
I am experimentig NextJS since a few days and i have a behavior i am not able to explain.
As i didn't find a way to get the "contextSpec" (request/response objects) from the RootLayout component (which is a first issue by itself)
i built a home made way to find my user session back from there, using the next cookie lib (if anyone has a tips to avoid that it would be really great!), aand by setting a cookie from my middleware (which appears to be the only place we can fetch the user session when beinng server side).
It's not really clean, but i thought i could try to find a better solution later.
However, i am experimenting a weird behavior, after setting a new cookie from the middleware, i got the previous version of it from my RootLayout.
I also tried to delete the cookie from the middleware, and RootLayout was able to find it after that!
If i refresh the page, it is well sync, it is like the RootLayout have the cookie 1 version earlier at every request.
Do you know what coud be the problem?
Thanks
middleware.ts
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

const response = NextResponse.next();

const idToken = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
nextServerContext: { request, response },
operation: async (contextSpec) => {
    try {
        const session = await fetchAuthSession(contextSpec);

        if (!session.tokens) {
          response.cookies.delete("my_custom_cookie");
          return;
        }

        response.cookies.set(
          "my_custom_cookie",
          JSON.stringify(session.tokens.idToken?.payload),
          {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            sameSite: "strict",
          },
        );

        return session.tokens.idToken;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      }
    },
});

RootLayout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const idTokenCookie = cookieStore.get("my_custom_cookie");
  const idToken = idTokenCookie ? JSON.parse(idTokenCookie.value) : null;

  console.log("EMAIL FROM ROOT LAYOUT = ", idToken?.email); // always 1 step/refresh late from middleware when i update my email

  const user = {
    email: idToken?.email,
  };

  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning={true} lang="fr">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider initialUser={user}>
          {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

EDIT: I have build an even simple middleware to focus on the cookie issue:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = { email: Math.random() };

  const response = NextResponse.next();

  response.cookies.set("my_custom_cookie", JSON.stringify(token));

  console.log("EMAIL FROM MIDDLEWARE = ", token.email);

  return response;
}

When i log the cookie from RootLayout, i always see the number generated by Math.random from the previous request!

I have found a recent PR (not released yet) for this exact issue here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/65008
The fix should be available with the next release i guess!
